# How to send an object from imported package to another Activty

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-api

I've made an activity (A) that recovers a `List<Event>` from Google Calendar API in an AsyncTask, and then sends it from (A) to (B). The list isn't empty when putting it into the bundle:

```
bundle.putSerializable(KEY_EVENTS_LIST, (Serializable) items);
```

but it's null when I recover it in (B)

```
   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
   eventList = (List<Event>) b.getSerializable(MainActivity.KEY_EVENTS_LIST);
```

I don't know which other way I could send it from (A) to (B), or if I could send the List directly to B from the AsyncTask.

Comment: check if Event class is Serilizable.

Comment: @NoumanCh no, it isn't, nor is Parcelable

Comment: Are you adding the bundle to your Intent before starting the Activity B?

Comment: @BenoitTH yes, and I receive the bundle in B correctly. But the recovered object is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send serialized array list (ArrayList) using intent from **Activity A** to **Activity B**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
    intent.putExtra("list", serializedArrayListObject);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

In **Activity B**  in **onCreate** method

```
ArrayList<Event> list=getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
```

to get list from intent

Comment: That worked great, thanks!! The only problem I got now is that when doing a for with the list and setting a value from the list `Event e = eventList.get(i);` jumps `ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event`, but when doing the `for` in (A) it works fine

Comment: Hi Erik Christian Pardo, you clearly said that it is importing com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event class but you need to import Event class which is created by you in local so, remove that import and import your local Event class. i have one suggestion there are many event inbuilt classes are there so you better change class name to some other names like i.e CustomEvent

Answer (score 0):

The WorkAround you can do to tackle this creates an `Event` Class in your project with all the attributes of `Event`(another package) class and make your Event class a paracalable.

Before setting list to bundle convert it to your list and pass this list.

This is not a good solution but up to my knowledge it will work perfectly.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the List in background while sending it to the other activity, you can use sharedPreferences for that as shown below:-

1) You cannot directly save an arrayList in SharedPreferences, so you need to convert it to a set first by:-

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                    set.addAll(Your_ArrayList);
```

2) Save it using sharedPreferences:-

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF_STRING, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putStringSet("Key", set);
                    editor.apply();
```

where `MY_PREF_STRING` is declared globally as `public static final String MY_PREF_STRING = "MY_PREF";`

**Retrieve this using**

1) In another activity where you want to retrieve this just paste the code given below:-

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
    set2 = preferences.getStringSet("Key", Collections.singleton("0"));
```

2) You can again convert this to arrayList using:-

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.addAll(set2);
```